# Why is flutter pub get not finding my ssh-key for github?

Tags: git, flutter, github, ssh

My flutter App depends on a module privately hosted on github.
When I run `pub get` from Powershell, i get:

```
Git error. Command: `git clone --mirror ssh://git@github.com:dirkbo/repo-name.git C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\git\cache\repo-name-123ba`
stdout:
stderr: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\git\cache\repo-name-123ba'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
exit code: 128
```

When I copy the failed command and run directly in the same powershell:

```
git clone --mirror git@github.com:dirkbo/repo-name.git C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\git\cache\repo-name-123ba
```

Everything works fine:

```
Cloning into bare repository 'C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\git\cache\repo-name-123ba'...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/dirkb/.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Enumerating objects: 229, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (229/229), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (132/132), done.
remote: Total 229 (delta 13), reused 229 (delta 13), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (229/229), 19.32 MiB | 1.45 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (13/13), done.
```

In my `pubspec.yaml` I tried:

```
repo:
    git: ssh://git@github.com/dirkbo/repo-name.git
```

(result see above)

and

```
repo:
    git: git@github.com:dirkbo/repo-name.git
```

which gives me:

```
Git error. Command: `git fetch`
stdout:
stderr: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
exit code: 128
```

It seems like the batch command running `pub get` can't find my ssh key.

Comment: Could you try with specifing branch and dependency name via pubspec? Like: `dependencies: kittens: git: url: git@github.com:munificent/kittens.git ref: some-branch`

You could also try `ssh://git@github.com:munificent/kittens` (removing .git)

Comment: I already did try both your suggestions, it's the same outcome. 
It seems pub get is running in a different shell, where my ssh-key is unknown.

Comment: Are you running your app in visual studio code or android studio? or something else?

Comment: I tried in AndroidStudio and from Windows Powershell.

Comment: This might be related due to pathing issues? Powershell using the home directoy as default location whereas AndroidStudio roots from the projectfolder. This might be causing confusion depending on your SSH client and your OS. I assume that you are on Windows, right?

Comment: I am on windows, yes.  I thought about that, but its the same result, when I run `flutter pub get` from powershell directly and when I run from android studio. 
I suspect, flutter uses a different shell for its pub get command.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem was that Windows did't use the correct ssh programm and instead of openssh was using it's internal ssh program, which of course didn't know about my keys in openssh.

`git config --global core.sshCommand "'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe'"`

So after configuring git to use OpenSSH, `flutter pub get` finds my keys, asks for a password and pulls the package correctly.

Thanks to https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5641#issuecomment-421801704

Comment: Thank you man, you are a true life saviour.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my repository is public & the package in the subfolder. I set the path by the subfolder name where package located.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_pi:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:{username}/flutter-packages.git
      path: flutter_pi
      ref: master
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `flutter pub get` was running well, but `flutter pub upgrade` was erroring with

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

The [answer provided by @dirkbo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63952029/9997212) solved only part of the problem for me, since there still was a conflict in my system between `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` from Windows and `usr\bin\ssh.exe` from Git Bash. Here I'm picking OpenSSH to handle all the operations:

1. Running the PowerShell console as administrator, enable the OpenSSH service:

```
Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Manual
```

2. Running a new command prompt, start the OpenSSH service:

```sh
ssh-agent
```

3. Then check if the keys you want to use are listed here:

```sh
ssh-add -L
```

4. If they aren't, add them using `ssh-add`, inserting their respective password when prompted:

```sh
ssh-add C:\Users\%YOUR_USER%\.ssh\id_github_home
ssh-add C:\Users\%YOUR_USER%\.ssh\id_github_work
```

5. Tell Git to always use OpenSSH:

```sh
git config --global core.sshCommand "'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe'"
```

Then I could get to run `flutter pub upgrade` normally!

I think this already solves the problem, but I've also added an environment variable named [`GIT_SSH`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_miscellaneous):

```sh
set GIT_SSH=C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
```

Note that every time start your computer, you need to run step 2 before running `flutter pub upgrade`.

Answer (score -3):

Had the same problem a while ago, just fix your pubspec.yaml to:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_ui_kit_poc:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:xxxxxx/flutter_ui_kit_poc.git
      ref: master
```

Comment: This was among the things I tried that didn't work.

Comment: The OP has already mentioned he tried this.